# Xamarin iOS Binding conversion of method at runtime

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.ios-binding

I got stuck in an issue when I was writing **Xamarin Binding Library**.

**Prerequisites**

1. I have iOS Native Framework.
2. I have a Xamarin Forms Application.

I have to write Xamarin Binding Library, which I am successfully able to write.

Now I got stuck

**iOS Native Framework API (in MyClass.h)** :-

```
-(void)clearAllDishes:(NSError * _Nullable * _Nullable)error;
```

**Binding Code API (in ApiDefination.cs)** :-

```
[BaseType(typeof(NSObject))]
public interface MyClass
{
    // -(void)clearAllDishes:(NSError * _Nullable * _Nullable)error;
    [Export("clearAllDishes:")]
    void ClearAllDishes([NullAllowed] out NSError error);
}
```

**Now in Xamarin UI we have to call below method** :-

```
try {
MyClass obj = new MyClass();
obj.clearAllDishes()
} catch throws Custom Exception {
   // Assuming the MyClass will throw the exception, when NSError pointer passed in iOS Native Framework.
}
```

Now my requirement is from Xamarin UI I have to call a method `clearAllDishes()` and further in Xamarin Library Binding I have to handle the `clearAllDishes()` in such a way so that we can throw the exception to Xamarin UI from here and call the iOS Native API `clearAllDishes`.

Comment: Out of curiosity,  is there a reason it is a native method? If the original issue was finding a way to call a iOS specific logic from the Xamarin.Forms UI then using a DependencyService would  help solve that probme

Comment: Welcome to SO Apoorv! What issue are you seeing? Is the clearAllDishes() not accessible? Are you able to call that function in the AppDelegate file?